# React-navigation drawer wont open by slide gesture when scrollview is on current screen

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-navigation, drawer

I have ReactNavigation -> DrawerNavigation as a main navigator for my app and it holds StackNavigator as a base router for all app screens. Pretty basic setup i think. 
Hovever: the first screen consist of ScrollView wchich is oriented horizontally. This interferes with drawer's edge drag to open functionality. Sometimes it works - most of the time scrollview takes over the swipe gesture.

I already increased the edgeWidth param in order to make sure it's not causing the issue.

My guess is the scrollview captures the gesture. Is there a way to give the drawer priority or to somehow limit scrollview gesture area so it's not trigerred at the edge of screen?

Much appreciate your help